# Adjust Drag Gesture on Rotated View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture

I have an image on a view.

- added rotation to rotate the view
- added drag gesture to pan the image
- drag gesture works fine when image is not rotated
- once the view is rotated to certain angle the drag gesture gets disturbed, since view is rotated.

So, how to adjust the dragOffset and position based on the angle of rotation?

[image]

Code:

```
struct ImageView: View {
    @State private var dragOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var position: CGSize = .zero
    
    @State private var currentRotation: Angle = .zero
    @GestureState private var twistAngle: Angle = .zero
    
    public var body: some View {
        let rotationGesture = RotationGesture(minimumAngleDelta: .degrees(10))
            .updating($twistAngle, body: { (value, state, _) in
                state = value
            })
            .onEnded{ self.currentRotation += $0 }
        
        let dragGesture = DragGesture()
            .onChanged({ (value) in
                self.dragOffset = value.translation
            })
            .onEnded({ (value) in
                self.position.width += value.translation.width
                self.position.height += value.translation.height
                self.dragOffset = .zero
            })
        
        let gestures = rotationGesture
            .simultaneously(with: dragGesture)
        
        Image.placeholder320x192
            .offset(x: dragOffset.width + position.width, y: dragOffset.height + position.height)
            .rotationEffect(currentRotation + twistAngle)
            .gesture(gestures, including: .gesture)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not very clear what do you need. Rotation is just a visual effect, view's frame & coordinate system (including used in events, drag in this case) remain the same.

Comment: @Asperi - When i drag view top to bottom, it should drag top-bottom, but since view is rotated, the view is panned/dragged in rotated angle, which is not user-friendly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the modifiers matter. You currently have the `offset` *before* the rotation - therefore you are applying the offset *then* rotating. This makes the offset appear at an angle. Instead, you want to rotate and then offset.

Change:

```
Image.placeholder320x192
    .offset(x: dragOffset.width + position.width, y: dragOffset.height + position.height)
    .rotationEffect(currentRotation + twistAngle)
    .gesture(gestures, including: .gesture)
```

To this:

```
Image.placeholder320x192
    .rotationEffect(currentRotation + twistAngle)
    .offset(x: dragOffset.width + position.width, y: dragOffset.height + position.height)
    .gesture(gestures, including: .gesture)
```

Comment: Perfect! Though i have a trailing query, my view doesn't respond to touches when is 'simultaneously' add touch and magnification gesture, after playing around. Is it correct to add more than two gestures?

Comment: @Bista Yep, add as many transformations and gestures as you need